# eBay Revenue Statement Discrepancy

Tags: sec, financial-statements, annual-report

In the eBay's 10-K filing to the SEC in 2014, they said that their revenue in 2012 was $14,072m. But in their 2015 statement, it shows as $7,371m.

Why is there a discrepancy in these two filings?
Why weren't any amendments filed?

2015 Form: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1065088/000106508816000265/ebay201510-k.htm

2014 Form:
https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1065088/000106508815000054/ebay201410-k.htm

Comment: Refer to *Note 4 — Discontinued Operations* in the 2015 Form 10-K filing.

Comment: Similar question: [Why does eBay's 2018 Form 10-K filing show a different net revenue for 2018 than in its 2020 filing?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/140399/why-does-ebays-2018-form-10-k-filing-show-a-different-net-revenue-for-2018-than)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the footnotes. They sold PayPal. They removed the sales and expenses related to PayPal from their consolidated statements. Otherwise it would look like sales dropped from year x to year y.

Comment: ah so if you wanted to look at older data, you'd have to tease out Paypal somehow.... how would one go about doing that?

Comment: You mentioned one difference between the reports in 2014 and 2015, but most of the numbers in that table changed. The changes are due to PayPal being erased from the numbers in the table. It is possible that other tables in the the 2015 SEC filing, or another filing specify the exact numbers.