# Why does eBay's 2018 Form 10-K filing show a different net revenue for 2018 than in its 2020 filing?

Tags: investing, sec, financial-statements, ebay, edgar

eBay's 2018 10-K filing declares a net revenue for 2018 of **$10.746 billion**.

eBay's 2020 10-K filing declares a net revenue for 2018 of **$8.650 billion**.

Why is there a discrepancy?

Comment: Similar question about a discrepancy in 2014/2015: [eBay Revenue Statement Discrepancy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/105624/ebay-revenue-statement-discrepancy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The revenue was adjusted because of discontinued operations:

- In 2019, eBay sold its StubHub business.
- In 2020, eBay sold its Classifieds business.

|  | 2018 revenue (in billions) |
| --- | --- |
| StubHub | 1.083 |
| Classifieds | 1.013 |

10.746 - 1.083 - 1.013 = 8.650

Revenues from discontinued operations were subtracted to make the 2018 revenue more comparable with the 2020 revenue.

Reference: [eBay 2020 Form 10-K filing](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1065088/000106508821000006/ebay-20201231.htm) (*Note 4 — Discontinued Operations*)